# Difference between PGP and GPG

Tags: security, gnupg, pgp

What are the main differences between PGP (Pretty Good Privacy) and GPG (GNU Privacy Guard) in relationship with security in Ubuntu and Launchpad?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

PGP can refer to two things:

1. The [Pretty Good Privacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) software originally written by Phil Zimmermann, and now owned by [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/pgp).
2. The formats for keys, encrypted messages and message signatures defined by that software.  These have now been formalised as the [OpenPGP](http://www.openpgp.org/) standard.

The [GNU Privacy Guard (GPG)](http://www.gnupg.org/) software is an independent implementation of the OpenPGP standards, so you can use it to exchange encrypted messages with people using other OpenPGP implementations (e.g. Symantec's PGP).

Due to its popularity on Linux systems, it is also fairly common for people to incorrectly use the term "GPG" to refer to the whole OpenPGP cryptography system (e.g. 
"GPG keys" or "GPG signatures").  It is usually pretty clear what they mean from the context though.

Comment: I was confused by github using the term GPG key ... so this is wrong technically? You reassure me that my understanding was correct, thanks :)

Comment: This answer could be improved by being more clear about the term "GPG Keys" being the incorrect or correct usage.

Answer (score 31):

“PGP” stands for “Pretty Good Privacy.” It was developed by Phil Zimmermann. At first it was written as copyrighted freeware under the Gnu Public License. Later, PGP was upgraded and made into a propriety program. The rights for this program are traded around. The reason for this upgrade was legal defense costs and royalty issues related to the export laws of the USA. Now the PGP program is owned by PGP Corporation.

Only the command line version is not owned by PGP Corporation which is also not for sale.  PGP uses the RSA algorithm and the IDEA encryption algorithm. The PGP is considered to have Windows interface which is more polished

“GPG” stands for “Gnu Privacy Guard.” GPG is a re-write or upgrade of PGP. It does not use the IDEA encryption algorithm. This is to make it completely free. It uses the NIST AES, Advanced Encryption Standard. All the algorithm data is stored and documented publicly by OpenPGP Alliance. The main reason for this change is that AES costs less than IDEA and is considered more secure. Moreover, it is royalty free because it is not patented.  GPG is more compatible than the original PGP with OpenPGP. GPG is also based on a command line. Windows frontends are also available for GPG other than the command line.

Comment: Are you sure the original version was GPL? The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Early_history) just says that "No license was required for its non-commercial use".

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't ever GPL: if it was, there wouldn't have been a need for GPG to be a clean room implementation.

Comment: "GPG is a re-write or upgrade of PGP." That's false. GPG is an implementation of OpenPGP.

Comment: Are you the author of [this article](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-pgp-and-gpg/)? Your answer contains a word-for-word portion of that article and the article was written before your answer was.

Answer (score 10):

Gnu Privacy Guard and Pretty Good Privacy -- also referred to as GPG and PGP, respectively -- are data encryption and decryption solutions used for transferring and storing information securely. GPG and PGP are nearly identical, with the major difference between them being how they are licensed to the public.

Read more: The Difference Between GPG and PGP | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/info_12225332_difference-between-gpg-pgp.html#ixzz26DXDNpJy

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: The downside of links. Thankfully: [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150226012556/http://www.ehow.com:80/info_12225332_difference-between-gpg-pgp.html)

Comment: the downside is the dealing with links, not the link itself. The general idea of a links is: it never changes. This includes never become broken.